# import .py script on same folder

Tags: python, python-import

I've a python file named sample.py which has some functions and another python file from which I want to access the functions of the sample.py. I've tried the code below which is working fine if I include the directory in the import statement.

```
from Integrated.sample import *
```

But the folder can't be the same for my application. Also, I referred another problem in stackoverflow similar to my issue, tried one of the answers

```
from .sample import *
```

which gives the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.crypto'; '__main__' is not a package
```

directory structure:

```
-module 
  --__init__.py
  --sample.py
  --tester.py
```

Hoping for a solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the directory structure you are working with?

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file in the folder you want to put `sample.py`? You can import only from packages

Comment: @SanilSinaiBorkar updated the structure.

Comment: @Gabip yes I have __init__.py

Comment: and what error do you get when you run just:
`from sample import *`

Comment: @Gabip I mentioned that in the post. Module not found error

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same module, you can directly import the file as given below. Works for me.

sample.py

```
def myfun():
    print("Sample")
```

tester.py

```
from sample import myfun
myfun()
```

Output

```
$ python3 tester.py 
Sample
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you would like to import a python module from another python folder.
I see you already have a  `__init__.py` file that is needed to declare this folder is a python package.
Navigate to the file where you want to import the module.

`from root.parent.folder.file import function_name`

other way of doing it

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/helloworld"))
from helloworld import *
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try this and let u know. But these two python scripts are in the same folder. I want to access functions of sample.py in tester.py

Comment: Then you can just use `from sample import *`, this should work